# how can store parse json string data into locally textfile in phonegap ios?

Tags: ios, json, cordova

how store parse json string data  into localltext file first and next time fetching  data from local file it self this my code which i write

$.getJSON("my ruls ",function(data)

the above line am parseing json url and i need store that data into local text file then user second time read  data from local text file only  not json url ?

pls give some idea or suggestion or some links to achive this problem

i did this problem in ipohne

thanks & regards

Answer (score 0):

you can write your data using FileWriter in Phonegap (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter)

regards,